# CSS: anchor link hover is not working

Tags: html, css

What I want is when I hover over anchor element the hover class should be applied. But it seems like it's not working. `h1` element is inside the anchor element. So I have to select `h1` element using `a h1:hover` then only this class is being applied. **The only concern is when I apply color to h1 then hover stops working otherwise it works well.** I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone please help on this? Thanks. [Code pen to play](http://codepen.io/programmerhk/pen/YpmVMY?editors=1100)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="">
  <h1>This will not work on hover</h1>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a, a:link{
  color: teal;
}
a:hover{
  color: salmon;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
/* a h1:hover{
  color: salmon;
} */
```

```css
a, a:link{
  color: teal;
}
a:hover{
  color: salmon;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
/* a h1:hover{
  color: salmon;
} */
```

```html
<a href="">
  <h1>This will not work on hover</h1>
</a>
```

Comment: Why downvote am I missing somehting?

Comment: I don't think that you miss something, the question seems valid, no need to be downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS specificity doesn't work exactly as you think.

You can read more about this here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

About your problem you could change:

```
a:hover{
    color: salmon;
}
```

to

```
a:hover h1{
    color: salmon;
}
```

and it will work as the above selector is more specific from:

```
h1{
   color: magenta;
}
```

and as a result it will override it when `a` is hovered.

Final html/css for you to test what I said:

```
<a href="">
   Anchor Text
   <h1>Heading Text</h1>
</a>
```

and

```
a, a:link{
  color: teal;
}
a:hover{
  color: salmon;
}

a:hover h1{
  color: yellow;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
```

Comment: You mean when we set color in h1{}, it has higher specificity then a:hover{}.

Comment: `a` and `h1` are 2 different elements with different color properties. By referencing `h1`'s color you actually override the default `color:inherit` that `h1` has and assign your own color. You need to specify exactly when the h1 color will change by extending the selector to override h1's color.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2yqucrnd/1/)**

**css**

```
a, a h1:link{
  color: teal;
}
a h1:hover{
  color: salmon;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
/* a h1:hover{
  color: salmon;
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
a, a:link{
  color: teal;
}
a:hover h1 {
  color: salmon;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <h1>This will not work on hover</h1>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missing `#` also , i have added one css

```
a:hover h1{
 color: salmon;
}
```

```css
a, a:link{
  color: teal;
}
a:hover{
  color: salmon;
}

a:hover h1{
  color: salmon;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
/* a h1:hover{
  color: salmon;
} */
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <h1>This will not work on hover</h1>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
a, a:link{
  color: teal;
}
a:hover h1 {
  color: salmon;
}

h1{
  color: magenta;
}
/* a h1:hover{
  color: salmon;
} */
```

```html
<a href="">
  <h1>This will not work on hover</h1>
</a>
```

Hope this helps!